# Remove class names from all 'a' childs?

Tags: javascript

I want to remove classnames from all 'a' elements inside another one with a ceratin ID.

```
<ul id="something">
<a class="a"></a>
<a class="a"></a>
<a class="a"></a>
</ul>
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery :**

`$('#something a').removeClass("a")`

**Java Script :**

`document.getElementById("something").removeAttribute("class",0)`
secont parameter 0 for non case sensitive search

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery, you can do

```
$('#something a').removeClass('a');
```

If you're not already in a document ready situation, you can do:

```
$(function() {
    $('#something a').removeClass('a'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify that you're using jQuery, so here's a non-jQuery solution:

```
var links = document.getElementById('something').getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
    links[i].className = '';
}
```